# Google font is blocking render despite using media=print

Tags: html, lighthouse, google-font-api, web-performance

I am using the below code to fetch Google font. Despite of using `media="print"`, lighthouse detects the font to be render-blocking. How do I make it non-blocking?
`<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" onload='this.media="all",this.onload=null' href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap">`

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide a test page that would be useful. I quickly created two tests to prove that it works correctly with Lighthouse

[Render Blocking - media="all"](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow-68676047.glitch.me%2Fblocking.html)

[Non Render Blocking - media="print"](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow-68676047.glitch.me%2F)

Answer (score 0):

I use this...

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheet.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'" />`

I'm not sure what `onload='this.media="all",this.onload=null'` would do...

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" onload='this.media="all",this.onload=null' href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap">`